# docker node randomly starts giving operation timed out

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, networking

I still don't know if the issue is with docker networking, node, or the connection from node to mysql.
But I have a docker that contains express gateway for api management. Every once in a while it starts giving `Operation timed out`

The error is coming from nodejs but when it happens :

- I can't see anything in the logs of the container
- Running tcpdump from the server shows a call being made to the docker api but returns a response of 500 (when running correctly i can see after it the call to the port 3306 to connect to the database)
- Running tcpdump from inside the docker container returns absolutely nothing (when working correctly I can see the calls)
- Calls that don't require a database connection work correctly! but still i can't see their logs in the container nor their calls inside tcpdump

It's as if the server is calling another docker, but i searched all volumes, images, there's no duplicate.

I tried to check the following :

- Resources on the same machine
- Resources on the database machine
- tcpdump with wireshark on both the server and the docker
- Add connection pooling to sequelize (In case a connection to the database is causing the block sometimes)
- Checking all oauth2 routes in case it's redirecting to localhost server or anything
- Literally adding logs everywhere just to see a log when this happens, but in vain
- telnet from the server to the localhost with external port and to 172.17.0.2 with internal port -> slight difference when i do it from localhost, after a while i receive a `Connection closed by foreign host`

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with logging in the container. The server stops responding, when it can not log requests.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean from inside the application ? because i'm logging to stdout with console.log.
but when this happens, i'm getting inside the docker and do netstat to check the listening port and it's on, the process of node is also running. (I just removed log_level DEBUG and will check if it makes a difference)

Comment: Yes, when I said 'the server' I meant the server running in the container.

Comment: I still have the issue, removed all logs (actually its just a test server, i only access it not that much load) any other thing i can try ? One more thing when it happens even restarting the container doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's normal for a docker container to hang like this or if an image is not correctly deleted, but things simply worked when I created the container with another name.